# drop-down menu link change colour

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have created a drop-down menu with links.
When i hover on the names, the drop-down menu appears.
Before adding the links, I could change colors of the name when the drop-down menu appears.
I made all names golden and the name over which I hover, turns black and gives drop-down menu and the name remains black while I go through drop-down menu.
But ever since I added links and changed all the names to golden, it refuses to turn black when drop-down menu appears

Answer (score 0):

Great question. What does your CSS target? I'd recommend inspecting the HTML with the Inspector tool on your browser. You can see what works, and what does not. Use the selector in your inspector, and then look at styles. In Google Chrome, styles are at the bottom.

Alternatively, please share your code for us to have a look at it. If you've added links by changing the HTML to a tags, for example, this could be the reason why the CSS does not work anymore.

Comment: i just managed to fix it. I just had to put . main-menu ul li:hover > a{ color:black; }  i feel so emotional. I've been struggling for the last 2 hour with this thing